# Establish location-affinity between two users from their geotags?

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, tags, geotagging

**The Idea.**
I would like to build a function like:

```
location_affinity(user_a, user_b)
```

which establish a location affinity between two users. In particular, this function will return a float number between 0 (no affinity) and 1 (max affinity) indicating how much places user_a has been correspond to places user_b has been. e.g.: If user_a ALWAYS stays with user_b and follows him to every places he go, I'm expecting a "1" as result. If user_a lives far away from user_b and they never got even close to each other, I'm expecting a "0" as result.

**The Data.**
Each user has a list of points(latitude, longitude) where he has been, and those points were already extracted from user's Facebook geotags.
To visualize this: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYUrF.png)

- Red "X"s are points(lat, lng) user_a has been.
- Green "X"s are points(lat, lng) user_b has been.
- Blue area represent the overlap.

**The Question.**
Are there any known algorithms which, based on two users' map points list, can establish the affinity (which I gather it depends on the overlap area)?
If not, which keywords should I search for?

**Additional.**
I'm trying to build Python functions with Spark. Are there any integrations?

Thank you.

Comment: How many points are there in each users point list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

First we use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) to determine the distances between each point from `user_a` to each point from `user_b` to find the closest point for each. We then use the exponential function to exponentially suppress higher distances. The constant `c` determines how large this suppression is, smaller means large distances have a higher suppression (you will need to scale it to make sense in your actual units). Then we just look at the mean of that metric.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def affinity(user_a, user_b, c=0.1):
    dists = cdist(user_a, user_b)
    return (np.exp(-dists.min(axis=0)/c)).mean()
```

This has the nice property that if the two sets of points are exactly equal, it returns `1`.

```
user_a = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
user_b1 = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
user_b2 = user_a.copy()

print(affinity(user_a, user_b1))
# 0.85169834916
print(affinity(user_b1, user_a))
# 0.856871315902
print(affinity(user_a, user_b2))
# 1.0
```

It has a small problem, though, as you can see above. This function is not symmetric. However, we can make it symmetric by considering both equally:

```
def affinity(user_a, user_b, c=0.1):
    dists = cdist(user_a, user_b)
    min_dists = dists.min(axis=0), dists.min(axis=1)
    return np.concatenate([np.exp(-x/c) for x in min_dists]).mean()

print(affinity(user_a, user_b1, 0.01))
# 0.271448093071
print(affinity(user_b1, user_a, 0.01))
# 0.271448093071
print(affinity(user_a, user_b2, 0.01))
# 1.0
```

Of course you can use many different metrics to determine the fall-off of larger distances. Here I chose `exp(-x)`, but you could also use `1 - tanh(x)` or `tanh(1/(x+epsilon))` (the epsilon is needed to avoid a divison by zero in case two points are exactly identical). This results in different behaviour:
[image]

Actually, you could use 1 - any function defined [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/869150/414400).